# Change default constructor argument value (inherited from parent class) in subclass

Tags: python, constructor, arguments, subclass

I have a `Parent` class with a default value for the attribute `arg2`. I want to create a subclass `Child` which has a different default value for the same attribute.
I need to use `*args` and `**kwargs` in `Child`.

I tried the following, but it is not working:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1='something', arg2='old default value'):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

        print('arg1:', self.arg1)
        print('arg2:', self.arg2)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.arg2 = kwargs.pop('arg2', 'new value')
```

This is not working. In fact, I get:

```
>>> c = Child()
arg1: something
arg2: default value # This is still the old value
>>> c.arg2
'new value' # Seems more or less ok

>>> c = Child('one', 'two')
arg1: one
arg2: two
>>> c.arg2
'new value' # This is wrong, it has overridden the specified argument 'two'
```

Comment: This is bound to happen; in the second example `arg2` is `args[1]`, not `kwargs['arg2']`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, and I can't seem to find a good way to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the default in `kwargs` before passing it on to `super()`; this is tricky as you need to ensure that the same value is not already in `args` too:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) < 2 and 'arg2' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['arg2'] = 'new value'
        super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This relies on knowing how many arguments are there to fill however. You'd have to use introspection of `super().__init__` for this to work in the general case:

```
from inspect import getargspec

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super_init = super().__init__
        argspec = getargspec(super_init)
        arg2_index = argspec.args.index('arg2') - 1  # account for self
        if len(args) < arg2_index and 'arg2' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['arg2'] = 'new value'
        super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You'd be much better off specifying *all* defaults instead:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, arg1='something', arg2='new value'):
        super(Child, self).__init__(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2)
```

Comment: Doesn't this risk having two values for `arg2`, passing it both positionally *and* by keyword?

Comment: This in fact fails for `Child('one', 'two')`: `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'arg2'`

Comment: @jonrsharpe: yes, there is that risk, I'll adjust.

Answer (score 2):

You've actually changed the signature of the class.  Basically, with:

```
def foo(a=1, b=2):
   ...
```

you can call by position, *or* by keyword:

```
foo(2, 3)
foo(a=2, b=3)
```

With:

```
def bar(**kwargs):
   ...
```

you can't call with positional arguments any more:

```
bar(2, 3)  # TypeError!
```

Your actual code has additional complications because you have `*args` in there which eat up all of your positional arguments.

---

The most robust advice I can give you is to preserve the signature when you override the method:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, arg1='something', arg2='new value'):
        super(Child, self).__init__(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2)
```

This (unfortunately) isn't a DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) as you'd probably like -- You have to specify `'something'` twice.  You could turn it into a global constant, or change the signature of `Parent.__init__`.

Alternatively, you could do a bunch of introspection to work with the signature of the parent class to make sure that you're passing the correct arguments in the right ways -- but I doubt very much that it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't satisfied with either solution and came up with the one below. It introduces the defaults as class attributes which are loaded if the default is None:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Parent:
    _arg1_default = 'something'
    _arg2_default = 'old default value'

    def __init__(self, arg1=None, arg2=None):
        if arg1 is None:
            arg1 = self._arg1_default
        if arg2 is None:
            arg2 = self._arg2_default

        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

        print('arg1:', self.arg1)
        print('arg2:', self.arg2)


class Child(Parent):
    _arg2_default = 'new value'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Call Parent without arguments (use defaults)')
    parent = Parent()
    print('Call Child without arguments (use defaults)')
    child = Child()
    print('Call 2nd Child with custom arguments ("one", "two")')
    child2 = Child('one', 'two')
    print('Query arg2 of 2nd child')
    print(child2.arg2)
```

Yields:

```
Call Parent without arguments (use defaults)
arg1: something
arg2: old default value
Call Child without arguments (use defaults)
arg1: something
arg2: new value
Call 2nd Child with custom arguments ("one", "two")
arg1: one
arg2: two
Query arg2 of 2nd child
two
```